# Can I use Angular to retreive data from Mongodb?

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to get data from my MongoDB displayed in my HTML page. Is it possible to get this done by Angular or do I need a templating engine for this? I'm using Express on Node platform.

I've already managed to get my POST done with Angular.

Here is my server call to MongoDB:

```
router.get('/getdata', function(req, res, next){
  UserData.find()
    .then(function(doc){
      console.log('Data successfully retrieved');
      res.render('index', {items: doc});
    });
});
```

Now only my index page is a template(Jade). The rest of my pages are routed with Angular and are regular HTML pages. I thought there was a way to display MongoDB data with Angular in HTML using these quotes {{}}, but I dont't know how this works

Comment: yeah, if you're using angular, then your server should respond with json, not html. Your angular code then takes the json and updates some model. And your views magically update themselves to reflect current state of the model. It's a big change in mental model. I recommend you get an angular book. Or at least complete their tour of heroes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MEAN stack - display information from MongoDB in the front end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758288/mean-stack-display-information-from-mongodb-in-the-front-end)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create API in node.js which will directly connect to Mongodb, and then use that API in AngularJS to bind the data in HTML. You can check [Using AngularJS with MongoDB](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2301560)